# Minimal, Low-level Telnet API

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I've started Python some days ago and wrote a small Telnet implementation according to RFC 854 and RFC 5198. It is pretty low-level and sending messages directly isn't even supported. The highest abstractions are *commands* and *user data* where commands include negotiation (like "Do") and "general-purpose" commands (like "Go Ahead").
The best thing about it is that, using the `__bytes__` method, these data can be converted to their binary representation and directly embedded into a data stream using TCP or just storing it temporarily, making it very flexible.

**Code** (`libtelnet.py`):

```
# This module contains code and data to provide a slight abstraction from
# the socket module to provide Telnet client facilities.

import enum
import socket
import struct

# The Telnet protocol is based on communication between two NVTs (Network
# Virtual Terminals). They are an abstraction of terminals, so the protocol
# can operate independently of the actual terminal used.

# Standard Telnet option negotation syntax (partially quoted from
# RFC 854):
# - WILL XXX: indicate local party's desire (an offer) to begin performing
#             option XXX
# - DO/DON'T XXX: positive/negative acknowledgements of WILL XXX
# - DO XXX: tell other party to begin performing option XXX
# - WILL/WON'T XXX: positive/negative acknowledgements of DO XXX

# An NVT consists of a printer and a keyboard; the former for outputting
# information, the ladder for inputting it. By default, the NVT is a half-duplex
# device in line-buffered mode. This can be altered by options, though.

# The Go Ahead (GA) command is to be issued when the Telnet client has sent all
# data to the printed and no input from the keyboard is waiting to support
# "lockable" keyboards at a half-duplex connection, for instance, the IBM 2741:
# it is locked when the other end is sending. The GA command unlocks it again.
# The GA command's purpose is not to signalize an EOL; usually, the machine
# has other mechanisms for handling and identifying such a state, so a GA
# command would be superflous.
# Other Telnet commands:
# - IP (Interrupt Process): interrupt process due to an infinite loop, for
#                           example
# - AO (Abort Output): abort output of text. Example: cat test.txt, where
#                      test.txt is so huge, it takes some seconds to print
#                      all the content. If an AO is issued in between, the
#                      rest of the output is discarded and the shell awaits
#                      the next command.
# - AYT (Are You There): issued to check responsiveness of the local system
#                        when, for example, a computation takes very long.
# - EC (Erase Character): deletes the most recent character in the data stream.
#                         Takes control characters into account.
# - EL (Erase Line): delete the current line of input.

# Valid control characters. All other control characters are ignored by the NVT.
# "\r\n" is a newline, "\r\x00" is a pure carriage return, as specified by
# RFC 854.

PORT = 23


# Old CtrlChars class.
#class CtrlChars(enum.Enum):
#    NUL = "\x00"
#    LF = "\n"
#    CR = "\r"
    # RFC 5198 ADVISES AGAINST using the lower control characters; they "SHOULD
    # NOT be used unless required by exceptional circumstances."
#    BEL = "\a"
#    BS = "\b"
#    HT = "\t"
#    VT = "\v"
#    FF = "\f"

#    GOOD_CTRL_CHARS = (NUL, LF, CR)
#    BAD_CTRL_CHARS = (BEL, BS, HT, VT, FF)
    # TODO: RFC 5198 talks about "undefined control codes" - add support for
    # these and find out what they are!

# "Strictly-conforming" control characters as specified by RFC 854 and 5198.
class CtrlChars(enum.Enum):
    CRLF = "\r\n"
    CRNUL = "\r\x00"

    BEL = "\a"
    BS = "\b"
    HT = "\t"
    VT = "\v"
    FF = "\f"

# CONSTRAINTS IMPOSED BY RFC 5198:
# 1. The sequence CR NUL should not be used.
# 2. LF CR should not appear except for consecutive CR LF sequences
#    (CR LF CR LF).
# 3. HT and a bare LF are problematic. The RFC doesn't discourage its usage
#    explicitly but I dare propose avoiding them anyway

# TODO: RFC 5198 says:
# Appendix D.  A Note about Related Future Work
#
# Consideration should be given to a Telnet (or SSH [RFC4251]) option
# to specify this type of stream and an FTP extension [RFC0959] to
# permit a new "Unicode text" data TYPE.
# FIND OUT IF THIS HAS BEEN DESIGNED SO FAR AND IMPLEMENT IT THEN!

# Didn't know where else to put this...
IAC = 255    # Interpret As Cmd

class Commands(enum.IntEnum):
    SE = 240    # end of subnegotation parameters
    NOP = 241    # no-op
    DM = 242    # Data Mark portion of SYNCH
    BRK = 243    # NVT character BRK (indicating Break or Attention key was hit)
    IP = 244    # Interrupt Process
    AO = 245    # Abort Output
    AYT = 246    # Are You There
    EC = 247    # Erase Character
    EL = 248    # Erase Line
    GA = 249    # Go Ahead
    SB = 250    # subnegotation

    # Negotation codes:

    WILL = 251
    WONT = 252
    DO = 253
    DONT = 254

NEG_CMD_RANGE = [ Commands.WILL, Commands.DO ]


# Telnet options as specified by the IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers
# Authority):
class Options(enum.IntEnum):
    """The Telnet options as specified the IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers
    Authority). However, this class only contains the ones recognized by
    this implementation. The implementation will refuse every option not
    contained in here.
    """

    TRANSMIT_BIN = 0
    ECHO = 1
    RECON = 2
    SUPPRESS_GA = 3
    APPROX_MSG_SIZE_NEG = 4
    STATUS = 5
    TIMING_MARK = 6
    RCTE = 7
    OUT_LINE_WIDTH = 8
    OUT_PAGE_SIZE = 9
    NAOCRD = 10
    NAOHTS = 11
    NAOHTD = 12
    NAOFFD = 13
    NAOVTS = 14
    NAOVTD = 15
    NAOLFD = 16
    EXT_ASCII = 17
    LOGOUT = 18
    BM = 19
    DET = 20
    SUPDUP = 21
    SUPDUP_OUT = 22
    SEND_LOC = 23
    TERMINAL_TYPE = 24
    EOR = 25
    TUID = 26
    OUTMRK = 27
    TTYLOC = 28
    N3270_REGIME = 29 # A Python identifier must not start with a digit, so
                      # the N ("Negotiate") has been added
    X3PAD = 30
    NAWS = 31
    TERMINAL_SPEED = 32
    TOOGLE_FLOW_CTRL = 33
    LINEMODE = 34
    XDISPLOC = 35
    ENVIRON = 36
    AUTHN = 37
    ENCRYPT = 38
    NEW_ENVIRON = 39
    TN3270E = 40
    XAUTH = 41
    CHARSET = 42
    RSP = 43
    COM_PORT = 44
    SUPPRESS_LOCAL_ECHO = 45
    START_TLS = 46
    KERMIT = 47    # y'know Kermit the frog? ^^ Maybe derived from him...
    SEND_URL = 48
    FORWARD_X = 49

    # Big gap with unassigned option codes...

    TELOPT_PRAGMA_LOGON = 138
    TELOPT_SSPI_LOGON = 139
    TELOPT_PRAGMA_HEARTBEAT = 140

    # Another big gap with unassigned option codes...

    EXOPL = 255

class SuboptHandlers:
    """Contains handler functions, which are called when subnegotation
       should take place. They return a bytes object containing an adequate
       response to the subnegotation from the Telnet server.
    """

   #def hLINEMODE():
   # TODO: yet to be written

def _repr(self):
    return "<" + (", ".join([str(key) + "=" + str(value) for key, value in
    self.__dict__.items()])) + ">"

class Command:
    def _calc_bytes(self):
        data = [IAC, self.cmd.value]

        if self.option != None:
            data.append(self.option.value)
            data.extend([i.value for i in self.option_args])

        return bytes(data)

    def __init__(self, cmd, option=None, option_args=[]):
        # Used to protect against undefined commands. To add a new command,
        # augment the Command enum.
        if (not isinstance(cmd, Commands)):
            raise TypeError("invalid Telnet command")

        # Similar to the case above.
        if (not isinstance(option, Options)):
            raise TypeError("invalid Telnet option")

        self.__dict__["cmd"] = cmd
        self.__dict__["option"] = option
        # Direct assignment to calculate byte representation.
        self.option_args = option_args

    def __bytes__(self):
        return self._bytes

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value

        # Actually, it's superflous to recalculate the WHOLE bytes object but
        # it's the easiest to implement.
        # TODO: ELIDE THIS INEFFICIENCY!
        self.__dict__["_bytes"] = self._calc_bytes()

    def __repr__(self):
        return _repr(self)

class UserData:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data_str = ""

        # I think (it's untested) the lopp be replaced by
        # "".join([if (isinstance(i, CtrlChars) i.value else i for i in data])
        # but that would require (I think it would) two iterations over the
        # list. Half as fast as the lower loop.
        for i in data:
            if isinstance(i, CtrlChars):
                self._data_str += i.value
            else:
        # TODO: we don't check the normal strings for control
        # characters here yet. ADD THIS **EFFICIENTLY**!
                self._data_str += i

    def __bytes__(self):
        return bytes(self._data_str, "ASCII")

    def __str__(self):
        return self._data_str

    def __repr__(self):
        return _repr(self)

# TODO: add support for options and suboptions!
# options: http://www.iana.org/assignments/telnet-options/telnet-options.xhtml
```

The API isn't finished yet but I am just asking about the basic structure of it:

1. How is the inclusion convention in Python? In C++, you shouldn't do `using namespace xxx;` but apparently it's quite Pythonic to do `from xxx import *`. If this is true, my API will be problematic because things like `PORT` are not directly associated to Telnet and might collide with a TCP implementation using `PORT` as well.
2. Do I use `enum`s well? Or do I overuse them? Do they make sense here at all?
3. Is the code readable, comprehensible, and alright overall? My worst fear is that it is too similar to C++- and C-ish and I miss opportunities to write it the true Pythonic way.
4. I talked flexibility in the second paragraph. What do you think of that approach using `__bytes__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Q&A

1) This is wrong. Actually `from xxx import *` is considered bad practice, for 
the exact reason you point out. It is only acceptable for very specific modules 
like `pylab`, which have a specific intent doing so (setup a MATLAB-like
environment in this case).

2) Enums are very new in Python, so it is easy to argue that you don't need them
at all. But I feel your use is consistent, even if it seems quite proeminent
at the moment in front of the actual *do-something* part of your code.

### String Manipulation, Generator Expression

I focus on the `_repr` function. Avoid concatenating strings with the `+`
operator. This is because strings are immutable, so you actually create a copy
of concatenated strings "each time" (okay, sometimes Python is more intelligent
than that but this is off-topic for a start). Use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
whenever you can. You will improve readability.

You know what list comprehensions do. Well done. But remember that they 
**build** a list, eating up memory. For all functions that accept an iterable, 
you can replace this by a [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) (just remove the `[]`).

```
def _repr(self):
    return "<{members}>".format(
        members=", ".join(
            "{key:!s}={value:!s}".format(key=key, value=value)
            for key, value in self.__dict__.items()
        )
    )
```

Same remark for `UserData.__init__`:

> for + str + "+=" = FAIL

Place all string chunks in a list, join them at the end.

```
class UserData:
    def __init__(self, data):
        data_elements = []

        for i in data:
            if isinstance(i, CtrlChars):
                data_elements.append(i.value)
            else:
                data_elements.append(i)

        self._data_str = "".join(data_elements)
```

### Your note on inefficiency

You gain a lot by waiting for the very last moment to process data. At least in
performance: if you don't need, you don't do. You avoid unnecessary actions.
But also in readability. If you do things when you need them, it's more clear
why you do it, and also what you are doing.

> Now is better than never.
>   Although never is often better than *right* now.
>   — [*The Zen of Python*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), Tim Peters.

One idea is to setup an invalidation mechanism. This delays the creation of
the bytes to when it is really needed. Below is only an example.

```
class Command:
    def __init__(...):
        super().__setattr__("_bytes_valid", False)
        super().__setattr__("_bytes", b'')
        # ...

    def __bytes__(self):
        # Recalc on access if necessary (cache-like)
        if not self._bytes_valid:
            super().__setattr__("_bytes", self._calc_bytes())
            super().__setattr__("_bytes_valid", True)
        return self._bytes

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
        super().__setattr__("_bytes_valid", False)
```

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our
>   opportunities in that critical 3%.
>   — *Structured Programming with Goto Statements*, Donald Knut.

The question being are we *really* in that critical 3%? Considering how often 
the `__bytes__` method is supposed to be called (probably once before sending 
the command), and how many times an attribute is set (at least 3 times with 
`cmd`, `option` and `option_args`), IMHO the best solution in that case is

```
class Command:
    def __bytes__(self):
        return self._calc_bytes()
```

### Tips & Tricks

```
class Command:
    def __repr__(self):
        return _repr(self)
```

can be replaced by

```
class Command:
    __repr__ = _repr
```

This will save you a function call.

---

The last parameter of `Command.__init__` is a good candidate for [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

```
def __init__(self, cmd, option=None, *option_args):
```

---

Blocks cannot be empty. That's why you have to use the `pass` statement.

```
class SuboptHandlers:
    """Contains handler functions, which are called when subnegotation
       should take place. They return a bytes object containing an adequate
       response to the subnegotation from the Telnet server.
    """
    pass # There
```

### Final thoughts on design

*Of course, this is MY review, not THE review. My opinion can be discussed.*

(Beware, big blahblah ahead).

It is bad practice to code without having layed out a solid design. Roughly
speaking, you collect use cases and requirements, select an architecture and
refine your design. *Only then* you write code.

Extensibility shall be chosen *by design* and not *by failing a design*. 
Because it comes at the price of performance, readability and simplicity, it 
has to be a required feature of your design. *"if I want to add something"* is 
not a good reason. *"when I will add that feature"* is.

That's why, considering the actual state of your code, I suggest you use
functions rather than classes and standard containers rather than objects.

> Simple is better than complex. [...]
>   Flat is better than nested.
>   — [*The Zen of Python*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), Tim Peters.

```
def userdata_as_bytes(data):
    data_elements = []
    for i in data:
        if isinstance(i, CtrlChars):
            data_elements.append(i.value)
        else:
            data_elements.append(i)
    return ("".join(data_elements)).encode("ascii")

def command_as_bytes(command):
    # In this implementation example, command is just a tuple or a list
    # containing (cmd, option, ...). This is not required, but shows you
    # how standard containers can also be suited for encapsulation.
    # You could instead declare
    #    command_as_bytes(cmd, option=None, *option_args)
    cmd, option, *option_args = command

    # Validation
    if (not isinstance(cmd, Commands)):
        raise TypeError("invalid Telnet command")
    if (not isinstance(option, Options)):
        raise TypeError("invalid Telnet option")

    data = [IAC, cmd.value]

    if option is not None:
        data.append(option.value)
        data += [optarg.value for optarg in option_args]

    return bytes(data)
```

> Be lazy. Delay actions till you are sure you (will) need them.
>   — *A stupid quote*, Me

Comment: Why not keep `command_as_bytes(cmd, option=None, *option_args)` as a signature as proposed earlier?

Comment: I used `self.__dict__` in `self.__init__` to circumvent `self.__setattr__`, which will calculate the byte representation even though the needed fields haven't been set yet. Isn't that right? Also, why not classes? Is conversion via functions really the way to go despite `self.__bytes__`? Classes seem also more extensible if I want to add something. And regarding "[...] waiting for the very last moment to process data [...]": which part are you referring to in my/your code?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: One use of a class is to encapsulate information as a single object you can manipulate easily. Here the point is to show that you can use a tuple instead of an object and gain the same functionality (a single entity that you build and forget). I shall probably explain this in the answer.

Comment: Didn't you meant to ping @cad instead of me with your previous comment?

Comment: @cad: `self.__dict__`: My, bad. I removed it. I extended sections *Your note on inefficiency* and *Final thoughts on complexity* to answer your other questions. @MathiasEttinger: No, I was answering your question. Maybe the ping practice is different here than on SO? I'll check.

Comment: Ok, so I don't get it. I was simply asking why you wrote `def command_as_bytes(command):` instead of `def command_as_bytes(cmd, option=None, *option_args):` (as you suggested above) to avoid unpacking the parameters.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: This is an example of how the interface could look like, both solution have their advantage. I'm making there assumption that the function could be used in a code ressembling `command = get_cabbage_command(); send(command_as_bytes(command))`. This is only a suggestion on a convention.